# Visual Studio 2015 C# ANTLR

Tags: antlr4, antlr4cs

To convince my employers of the benefits of ANTLR and StringTemplate, I constructed a small demonstration first in Java.  But Java is not one of our preferred languages, so I translated it to C#.  Using VS2015 (Community Edition) and various instructions on the net I got only so far.  I now get

> ANTLR cannot generate 'org.antlr.v4.codegen.CSharp_v4_5_2Target' code as of version 4.3

Incompatible versions? Which versions of what libraries are compatible for a successful build.  I could not work out how to use GitHub. There didn't seem to be a package to download, and I could not see how to download a set of files to compile.

**Update 1**
Randomly installing versions of whatever I can find, I have now got it down to loads of errors like this from the generated code.

> CS0103 The name '_errHandler' does not exist in the current context

**Update 2**
I have subsequently tried (and failed) to get it going in VS2010(Express). I think that version is seriously hobbled. I can't get NuGet working on it. I am now going to try to install VS2013 as that seems to be the most commonly referred to in this ANTLR context. With VS2015 I have been through all the .NET versions I have installed on my machine back to v3, with no success. It now fails to generate the parsing code.

**Update 3 - Solved**
Problem solved! Use VS2013 and follow Sam Harwell's clear [instructions](http://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/wiki/Installation).  Some minor differences between Java and C# to work out when using StringTemplate